# Square brackets in application/x-www-form-urlencoded message format (wso2 ESB 5.0)

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to send a request through wso2 ESB 5.0.0 to external HTTP API  which require `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. I found this post:

[Sending Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded WSO2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331115/sending-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-wso2-esb)

and it's almost works, but this vendor also require parameters in array format like this:

`to[email@email.com][message_id]=message_id`

Unfortunately xml nor json doesn't allow me to build parameters with square brackets in xml node names or in json key names. Escaping through `%5B` `%5D` also won`t help.

I also tried ExpandingMessageFormatter but with no success - I can`t build  well-formed property and replace message of a body with it's content. For example:

```html
<property name="messageBody" scope="default" type="STRING" value="to%5Bemail%40email.com%5D%5Bmessage_id%5D=id&amp;to%5Bemail%40email.com%5D%5Breciver_name%5D=Name%20Surname&amp;smtp_account=2.xxx.smtp&amp;subject=Test%20temat&amp;html=%3Chtml%3E%3Cb%3ETEST%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E&amp;from=email%40email.com&amp;from_name=xxx"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>"$ctx:messageBody"</format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
```

or with EnrichMediator:

```html
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" property="messageBody" type="property"/>
        <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>
```

Please, any advise will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after the question, but maybe it will help someone. I put the script mediator before building

```
<script description="EncodedUrl" language="js"><![CDATA[resId = mc.getProperty('resId')
mc.setProperty("EncodedUrl", encodeURI("/rest/all/V1/api/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=resource_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=" + resId</script>
<property description="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('EncodedUrl')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

and it worked for me. We can even likely set the REST_URL_POSTFIX directly in the script.