# WSO2 ESB - Error Response when Post-Request - Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 EI 6.3v.I want to pass application/x-www-form-urlencoded data to the rezlive hotel Supplier. In hear i put my code and response.

**CODE**

```
<inSequence>
        <log category="WARN" level="full">
            <property name="API BEGIN" value="Test_Supplier API"/>
        </log>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <HotelFindRequest xmlns="">
                            $1
                        </HotelFindRequest>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='HotelFindRequest']/*"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*" name="xmlbody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log>
            <property expression="$ctx:xmlbody" name="Body======="/>
        </log>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        <property expression="$body" name="payload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="uri.var.url" scope="default" type="STRING" value="http://test.xmlhub.com/testpanel.php/action/findhotel"/>
        <call>
            <endpoint>
                <address format="pox" uri="http://test.xmlhub.com/testpanel.php/action/findhotel?XML={xmlbody}"/>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

**Body Log**

```
<HotelFindRequest>
<Authentication>
    <AgentCode>xxxxxxx</AgentCode>
    <UserName>xxxxx</UserName>
    <Password>xxxxxx</Password>
</Authentication>
<Booking>
    <ArrivalDate>22/05/2019</ArrivalDate>
    <DepartureDate>25/05/2019</DepartureDate>
    <CountryCode>AE</CountryCode>
    <City>968</City>
    <GuestNationality>LK</GuestNationality>
    <HotelRatings>
        <HotelRating>1</HotelRating><HotelRating>2</HotelRating>
        <HotelRating>3</HotelRating><HotelRating>4</HotelRating>
        <HotelRating>5</HotelRating>
    </HotelRatings>
    <Rooms>
        <Room>
            <Type>Room-1</Type>
            <NoOfAdults>2</NoOfAdults>
            <NoOfChilds>0</NoOfChilds>
        </Room>
        <Room>
            <Type>Room-2</Type>
            <NoOfAdults>1</NoOfAdults>
            <NoOfChilds>0</NoOfChilds>
        </Room>
        <Room>
            <Type>Room-3</Type>
            <NoOfAdults>2</NoOfAdults>
            <NoOfChilds>0</NoOfChilds>
        </Room>
        <Room>
            <Type>Room-4</Type>
            <NoOfAdults>3</NoOfAdults>
            <NoOfChilds>0</NoOfChilds>
        </Room>
    </Rooms>
</Booking>
```

**Response** comming as

```
<HotelFindResponse>
<error>Please provide agentcode.</error>
<error>Please provide username.</error>
<error>Please provide password.</error></HotelFindResponse>
```

But I pass **same configuration in POSTMAN**, give me the correct response.

[image]

I put the same configuration in Postman. I tried so meny ways to get response.All are failed. 
What is wrong with that code?.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with HTTP endpoint (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/HTTP+Endpoint) using post?

Payload factory already sets the body, so it should work right away as it will try to post it.

Comment: i tried that way. But still no solution. Hear is the code. `<http method="post" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="test.xmlhub.com/testpanel.php/action/findhotel">`

Comment: Ok. I think we should try setting the content type to the one you're trying to send. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331115/sending-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-wso2-esb

Comment: Maybe you can try this same request on another ESB version. Personally, I use 6.1, and I got no problems with requests to API endpoints yet. Unfortunately, I'll have no time to test the same on 6.3 anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "uri.var.xmlBody" property name instead of simple "xmlBody":

```
<property expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*" name="uri.var.xmlBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<call>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="pox" uri="http://test.xmlhub.com/testpanel.php/action/findhotel?XML={uri.var.xmlBody}"/>
        </endpoint>
</call>
```

Comment: `uri.var.xmlBody`  that one only property name. That one won't effect any thing.

Comment: did you try it before writing?

Comment: According to https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/HTTP+Endpoint "RESTful URI ... variables .. can be populated during mediation runtime using property values whose names have the "uri.var." prefix."

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? [from here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+Specific+Use+Cases)

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <root xmlns="">
                        <XML>$1</XML>
                     </root>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:xmlbody"></arg>              
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>             
         <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <call>
<http method="post" uri-template="test.xmlhub.com/testpanel.php/action/findhotel"/>
</call>
```